# Is there a way to pass an array to currentWhen in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to make a link stay 'active' on multiple routes, such as /#/users and /#/user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can reopen Ember's LinkView and do something like this (allows currentWhen to contain space delimited values)

```
Ember.LinkView.reopen({
    active: function() {
        // we allow link-to's currentWhen to specify multiple routes
        // so we need to check each one of them
        var loadedParams = Ember.get(this, 'loadedParams');
        var currentWhen = this['current-when'] || this.currentWhen;
        currentWhen = currentWhen || (loadedParams && loadedParams.targetRouteName);

        if (currentWhen && currentWhen.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                var currents = currentWhen.split(' ');
                router = Ember.get(this, 'router');

            for (var i = 0; i < currents.length; i++) {
                var isActive = router.isActive.apply(router, [currents[i]]);
                if (isActive)
                    return isActive;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return this._super();
    }.property('resolvedParams', 'routerArgs')
});
```

Comment: And starting with Ember 1.8, you can just set current-when with a space delimited sting of routes!

Comment: Where this should be defined using Ember App Kit?

Answer (score -1):

This is a total hack, but it works in Ember 1.0.0. To make links to users stay active when the user route is active:

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    activate: function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('[href="#/users"]').addClass("active");
        }, 0);
    }
});
```