# How to set link 'active' for multiple different routes in EmberJS

Tags: binding, ember.js

I'd like to set the 'active' class on an Ember link-to helper for more than one route, where the routes are *not* nested.
ie. if I have a link to route1 I would like it to be active when the current route is route1 or route2.

Something, like:

`{{#link-to 'route1' currentWhen="route1, route2"}}Things-N-Stuff{{/link-to}}`

My next ideal scenario is set (or find) a boolean when the route is active and then do something like:

```
{{#link-to 'route1' class="isRoute1:active isRoute2:active"}}Not-as-good{{/link-to}}
```

But I'd rather pick it up for free. Perhaps there is a default isRoutename boolean that isn't in the docs yet...?

---

No answers yet. I ended up doing this:

```
{{#linkTo "things" tagName="li" href=false}}
    <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}} {{bindAttr class="isThingsLinkActive:active"}}>Things</a>
{{/linkTo}}
```

And then in the App.ApplicaitonController

```
isThingsLinkActive: function(){
    return ['things.index','thing.index','stuff.index'].contains( this.get('currentPath') );
}.property('currentPath'),
```

It means I need to have something like thins in my app controller for each 'overloaded' link. Wouldn't it be cleaner to capture this entirely in the template using default flags/attributes generated by ember? I'm open to a more elegant solution... anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EmberJS Set Multiple Properties At Once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752805/emberjs-set-multiple-properties-at-once)

Comment: @PaulSweatte I don't think these are related at all. This question has to do with the link-to helper. The other one is about setting properties. If I'm wrong and you can figure out how to use setProperties to accomplish the goal I'd love to see it in a jsfiddle or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently as of [3.2](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.2/classes/LinkComponent/properties/current-when?anchor=current-when) the correct syntax is:

```
{{#link-to 'fruits.index' current-when="fruits.index apples.index"}}Link text{{/link-to}}
```

Sorry, tried to edit the original answer but the change is less than 6 characters.

Comment: Thanks for keeping this updated. I changed the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

According to the [link-to#active documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkComponent.html#property_active), you can do this by using a space delimited "currentWhen", but this requires Ember 1.8.

```
{{#link-to 'route1' currentWhen="route1 route2"}}Things-N-Stuff{{/link-to}}
```

This may also be a feature you can enable on earlier builds:

See 'ember-routing-multi-current-when' on https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/FEATURES.md

Alternatively, you can override the link-to helper with one of the methods described in this SO post:

[Is there a way to pass an array to currentWhen in EmberJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473807/is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-array-to-currentwhen-in-emberjs)

Comment: Thanks for responding to this year-old thread. Sometimes these features take a while, but I'm glad to see this was thought through and is (will be) supported.

Comment: Ahh, didn't actually notice the date, but it's still a relevant question today and I'm glad you asked it ;) good that it's been addressed by the Ember folks