# Make navigation item active when route doesn't match

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I noticed that using EmberJS, if the route you are on matches a link with the same path on your page, it takes automatically the class 'active'.

I'm currently building a navigation bar that is using this, but my concern comes from the fact that not all my routes match my navigation bar.

For example, when I'm in the route `/messages`, I'd like to make the item `/services` active.
Or when I'm in the route `/forums/history`, I'd like to make the item `/forums/archives` active. Even though this route is not in the navigation, I want to highlight an item which is related to it.

My navigation is generated from a json object that looks like that:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Forums",
    "link": "forums",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Latest"
        "link": "forums.latest"
      }
      {
        "label": "Archives"
        "link": "forums.archives"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I had a couple of ideas that I don't like, that's why I'm coming here to have your advises. Here are my ideas:

- Define a property into the view to define which item should be active in the navigation:

*views/forums/history.js:*

```
Ember.View.extend({
  navigationActiveItem: 'forums.archives'
});
```

- Define in my json object the list of links that will highlight the item

*json file:*

```
[
  {
    "label": "Forums",
    "link": "forums",
    "children": [
      {
        "label": "Archives"
        "link": "forums.archives",
        "makeActive": ["forums.history", "forums.records"] //If you are on one of those route, it will active forums.archives
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

*router.js:*

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('forums', function () {
    this.route('latest');
    this.route('archives');
    this.route('history');
  });
});
```

Do you have any better suggestion to do such a thing?
Thanks

Comment: Can you add your router code? If they are properly nested, the nav will get the active class

Comment: I edited the question with the router.

Comment: How is history related to archive, where is services and messages?

Comment: Those are just example of what I need. services and messages are at the same level than forums. history is related to archives because I want it to be.

Comment: Is nesting the routes an option?

Comment: No sorry, it's not an option.

Answer (score 4):

Use the current-when parameter of {{#link-to}}. It will allow you to define alternative routes that cause the link-to to be active.

Since ember 1.8, current-when can accept a space delimited string of routes. For an implementation that works in 1.7, check out [Is there a way to pass an array to currentWhen in EmberJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18473807/is-there-a-way-to-pass-an-array-to-currentwhen-in-emberjs/23838162)

Comment: It does, but you can then add some css rules that will display the links the way you want (i.e. active shown as inactive and everything else as active)

Comment: To have active as an inactive item, that's not really css semantic and more a 'trick'

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. Did you try {{#link-to 'services' current-when='messages'}}Services{{/link-to}} and {{#link-to 'forums.archives' current-when='forums.history'}}Archives{{/link-to}} ?

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this is by setting properties in my application controller.

(This assumes that your nav bar template is in `application.handlebars`)

For example, if you want your "Forums" tab to be active on any `forums` route you could create a property called something like `isForums` which would look like this:

```
isForums: function(){
  return this.get('currentPath').split('.')[0] === 'forums';
}.property('currentPath')
```

You could then access this from `application.handlebars` like so:

```
<li {{bind-attr class="isForums:active"}}>
  {{#link-to "forums"}}Forums{{/link-to}}
</li>
```

This adds the `active` class to the `<li>` if `isForums` evaluates to true.

Comment: The issue with this approach is when you have a website with hundred of pages, it starts to be messy to have computed property for all pages you need to define.